# How to dismiss an individual entry from the Calendar Notifications list?

Tags: notifications, 4.4-kitkat, google-calendar

On my Nexus 5 phone running Android 4.4, if I have several calendar notifications come at the same time, I can easily dismiss them all at once by either:

1) pulling down the notification menu (screenshot below) and then swiping to the right over the entry labeled, say, "3 events" as seen here:

[image: Notification menu screenshot]

2) tapping on "3 events" from the notification menu to display the Calendar notifications list and then tapping the "Dismiss all" text at the bottom, like in this screenshot:

[image: Calendar notifications list screenshot]

I'd like to dismiss individual event notifications from the calendar notification list seen in option #2 above, for those times when I get a couple activities done but not all at once.  I see no way to do that, though, other than to tap on each entry, which then pulls up its full calendar entry, and then tapping the back button, which brings me to my full calendar view, and then going back into the notification menu, selecting the events entry, and repeating.  Swiping to the right over an individual entry on the calendar notifications list does nothing.

Is there a quicker way to remove select entries directly from the calendar notification list that I'm missing?  On my old Android 2.3 phone, I could mark a little checkbox next to each entry on the calendar notification list and dismiss only selected reminders, but I see no way to do that in Android 4.4.

Comment: I have the same issue on Android 4.1 Jelly Bean.  And like you I used to be able to do it on my old gingerbread phone.  Annoying that is seems they actually took functionality away in later versions.